# How to add class .hidden-item to all item except the first child using vanilla JS

Tags: javascript, html, css

I need help with the following in vanilla JS.  I need to add class “`.hidden-item`” to all “item” except the first child using vanilla JS.
Onclick button it show the hidden item and again click on button it hide those displayed item expect the first child.

```js
 const button = document.querySelector('.toggle-button');
    const buttonText = document.querySelector('.toggle-button--text');
    const hiddenItems = document.querySelectorAll('.hidden-item');
    let isHidden = true;

    button.addEventListener('click', () => {
      buttonText.textContent = isHidden
        ? 'Read Less'
        : 'Read More';

      button.classList.toggle('open');

      isHidden = !isHidden;
      hiddenItems.forEach(item => item.classList.toggle('hidden'));
    });
```

```css
.hidden {
      display: none;
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Read More or Read Less</title>

</head>
<body>
  <p class="item">Atilla was born and bred in Stuttgart which lies in the Swabian region of Germany. Raised by Turkish parents, he was fully bilingual by the age of five and grew up speaking both languages. In 2009 he moved to Istanbul where he studied acting for three years at the Müjdat Gezen Conservatoire, before coming to the UK and furthering his training with a postgraduate degree at the Oxford School of Drama.</p>
  <p class="item hidden">Atilla’s work is highly versatile. It spans languages, accents and various genres. He lends his voice on a regular basis to a broad range of well-known clients and brands.</p>
  <p class="item hidden">He voiced Assyrian King Ashurbanipal for the British Museum’s exhibition trailer and brought to life Persian leader Cyrus the Great in the video game ‘Total War: Arena’.</p>
  <p class="item hidden">For BBC Radio 4 he played a Turkish spy in ‘Journey into Fear’ and German POW in the long-running series ‘Home Front’.</p>
  <p class="item hidden">For Big Finish Productions he worked alongside Sheridan Smith and Paul McGann on ‘Doctor Who’, followed by a two-hander opposite John Barrowman in ‘The Lives of Captain Jack’.</p>

  <div class="toggle-button">
    <div class="toggle-button--text">Read More</div>
  </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: you have no class `hidden-item` in your code

Comment: Good to see another person rejecting the convoluted nonsense of frameworks and learning real code. No can clarify that at the bottom of your posts by stating, "`No frameworks or libraries.`".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You almost had it!

First thing: you don't have a '.hidden-item' class.
Changing that to select all p tags with class 'item' and then running the forEach loop using the index of each item and toggling the 'hidden' class for every item except the first one.

```js
const button = document.querySelector('.toggle-button');
const buttonText = document.querySelector('.toggle-button--text');
// Changed .hidden-items to .item
const hiddenItems = document.querySelectorAll('.item');
let isHidden = true;

    button.addEventListener('click', () => {
      buttonText.textContent = isHidden
        ? 'Read Less'
        : 'Read More';

      button.classList.toggle('open');

      isHidden = !isHidden;
      // added the index as second parameter to ignore the first item.
      hiddenItems.forEach((item, i) => {
        if (i > 0) item.classList.toggle('hidden')
      });
    });
```

```css
.hidden {
  display: none;
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Read More or Read Less</title>

</head>
<body>
  <p class="item">Atilla was born and bred in Stuttgart which lies in the Swabian region of Germany. Raised by Turkish parents, he was fully bilingual by the age of five and grew up speaking both languages. In 2009 he moved to Istanbul where he studied acting for three years at the Müjdat Gezen Conservatoire, before coming to the UK and furthering his training with a postgraduate degree at the Oxford School of Drama.</p>
  <p class="item hidden">Atilla’s work is highly versatile. It spans languages, accents and various genres. He lends his voice on a regular basis to a broad range of well-known clients and brands.</p>
  <p class="item hidden">He voiced Assyrian King Ashurbanipal for the British Museum’s exhibition trailer and brought to life Persian leader Cyrus the Great in the video game ‘Total War: Arena’.</p>
  <p class="item hidden">For BBC Radio 4 he played a Turkish spy in ‘Journey into Fear’ and German POW in the long-running series ‘Home Front’.</p>
  <p class="item hidden">For Big Finish Productions he worked alongside Sheridan Smith and Paul McGann on ‘Doctor Who’, followed by a two-hander opposite John Barrowman in ‘The Lives of Captain Jack’.</p>

  <div class="toggle-button">
    <div class="toggle-button--text">Read More</div>
  </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple options to select these hidden elements only ( but not the first item), based on your existing code, you just need to edit your selector from `('.hidden-item')` to be `('.item.hidden')`

```js
const button = document.querySelector('.toggle-button');
    const buttonText = document.querySelector('.toggle-button--text');
    const hiddenItems = document.querySelectorAll('.item.hidden');
    let isHidden = true;

    button.addEventListener('click', () => {
      buttonText.textContent = isHidden
        ? 'Read Less'
        : 'Read More';

      button.classList.toggle('open');

      isHidden = !isHidden;
      hiddenItems.forEach(item => item.classList.toggle('hidden'));
    });
```

```css
.hidden {
      display: none;
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Read More or Read Less</title>

</head>
<body>
  <p class="item">Atilla was born and bred in Stuttgart which lies in the Swabian region of Germany. Raised by Turkish parents, he was fully bilingual by the age of five and grew up speaking both languages. In 2009 he moved to Istanbul where he studied acting for three years at the Müjdat Gezen Conservatoire, before coming to the UK and furthering his training with a postgraduate degree at the Oxford School of Drama.</p>
  <p class="item hidden">Atilla’s work is highly versatile. It spans languages, accents and various genres. He lends his voice on a regular basis to a broad range of well-known clients and brands.</p>
  <p class="item hidden">He voiced Assyrian King Ashurbanipal for the British Museum’s exhibition trailer and brought to life Persian leader Cyrus the Great in the video game ‘Total War: Arena’.</p>
  <p class="item hidden">For BBC Radio 4 he played a Turkish spy in ‘Journey into Fear’ and German POW in the long-running series ‘Home Front’.</p>
  <p class="item hidden">For Big Finish Productions he worked alongside Sheridan Smith and Paul McGann on ‘Doctor Who’, followed by a two-hander opposite John Barrowman in ‘The Lives of Captain Jack’.</p>

  <div class="toggle-button">
    <div class="toggle-button--text">Read More</div>
  </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest a simplified approach that reduce a bit the complexity: hide all elements except the first one via CSS, and when the button is clicked toggle a class *only* to a common parent (e.g. the `body` element, but it could be any other common intermediate wrapper, if you prefer) which reveals the hidden content, and not to *every* paragraph.

Use a real `button` element for your switch (so it is accessible) and use `data-*` attributes, so the text of the button is not hardcoded in the script, the code is more maintainable, and the labels could be eventually more easily localized.

```js
document.querySelector('.toggle-button').addEventListener('click', function() {
  document.body.classList.toggle('reveal');
  this.textContent =  document.body.matches('.reveal')? 
    this.dataset.textExpanded :
    this.dataset.textCollapsed;
    
});
```

```css
body:not(.reveal) .item + .item {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <p class="item">Atilla was born and bred in Stuttgart which lies in the Swabian region of Germany. Raised by Turkish parents, he was fully bilingual by the age of five and grew up speaking both languages. In 2009 he moved to Istanbul where he studied acting for three years at the Müjdat Gezen Conservatoire, before coming to the UK and furthering his training with a postgraduate degree at the Oxford School of Drama.</p>
  <p class="item">Atilla’s work is highly versatile. It spans languages, accents and various genres. He lends his voice on a regular basis to a broad range of well-known clients and brands.</p>
  <p class="item ">He voiced Assyrian King Ashurbanipal for the British Museum’s exhibition trailer and brought to life Persian leader Cyrus the Great in the video game ‘Total War: Arena’.</p>
  <p class="item">For BBC Radio 4 he played a Turkish spy in ‘Journey into Fear’ and German POW in the long-running series ‘Home Front’.</p>
  <p class="item">For Big Finish Productions he worked alongside Sheridan Smith and Paul McGann on ‘Doctor Who’, followed by a two-hander opposite John Barrowman in ‘The Lives of Captain Jack’.</p>
  
  
  <button class="toggle-button" 
     data-text-collapsed="Read More" 
     data-text-expanded="Show Less">
    Read More
  </button>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

:nth-child(n+2) selects all but the first, e.g document.querySelectorAll('div:nth-child(n+2)').